# EC2 instance created via Terraform not connecting to the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I apply the below configuration I get an AWS Linux EC2 instance running connected to the default VPC with the default public subnet connected to the default public IGW.

When I ping the public URL of the instance. the hello world webpage doesn't open, and the page errors out

I also SSH into the instance and pinged google.com, which also didn't work.

Can anyone kindly point me in the direction which would resolve this issue?

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance_1" {
  ami             = "ami-05548f9cecf47b442"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.instances.name]
  key_name        = var.ssh_key
  user_data       = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    yum update -y
    yum install -y httpd
    systemctl start httpd
    systemctl enable httpd
    echo "<h1>Hello World $(hostname -f)</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
    EOF
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instances" {
  name = var.instance_security_group
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_http_inbound" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instances.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_ssh_inbound" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instances.id
}
```

**Trails**:

1. I tried putting the script into another file and referencing it. (**didn't work**)
2. I tried Using other AMIs and other data scripts. (**didn't work**)

Comment: For the outbound connectivity (pinging google), none of your security groups define `egress` rules. See example of egress rule in the Terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/2.56.0/docs/resources/security_group).

Comment: For accessing the page hosted on the EC2 instance, make sure you use `http` and not `https` when trying to access it. When you put the address in Chrome/Firefox, make sure you explicitly say that your url starts with `http://...`.

Comment: Yes, I have ensured http but still get 'This site can’t be reached' error. Thank you for the egress tip, yes you are right.

Comment: The page wont load anyway. Most likely the instance failed to install `httpd`, because you do not have the `egress` rule.

Comment: Possibly, let me try that and report back :).

Comment: Thank you, Ervin, It worked, it needed a security group for the outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as mentioned in the comments is that the configuration was missing an Egress security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_all_outbound" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.instances.id
}
```